# Accessing localStorage from subdomain

Tags: javascript

I was wondering whether there was a way to access localStorage on a subdomain.
For example, if you set
localStorage.name = "Jogn Smith";
on example.com and you wanted to retrieve this on a domain such as blog.example.com, would this be possible?
Would there be an additional verification step to prove that I own both the apex domain and subdomain?

Comment: Also: https://gist.github.com/buren/8d7c831822bc474164cc37dd522c2d1d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible, because localStorage is a Web-API-method of the/a browser, not the/a server.